# Angular Input Date display from datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I am populating all the data in a mat-datatable and have options to edit..
when the user clicks on edit all the form fields populate with the data ..but date isnt populating..i have manipulated date using datepipe.all fields are populating except date
here is my code.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Jan</mat-label>
    <div [formGroup]='formGroup'>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1"
            name="jan" formControlName='JAN'
            [(ngModel)]="stockReportDetails.jan">
    </div>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker> 
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts file

```
this.stockReportDetails.jan =
    this._dateFormatPipe.transform(this.stockReportDetails.jan);
```

---

[here is the datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXwBl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBNs8.png)

Comment: your question is not having proper info

Comment: add information like what is the response you receive from db and how your are assigning to formGroup

Comment: I am.showing the. Data in the data table https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXwBl.png like this and. Populating these fields in the input form